# PDO database with multiply users, what do I need to fill in as host

Tags: c#, php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to make an C# application that puts information inside the MySQL database. This is for a school project.

I'm working with a group and they also need to acces the database, and I'm wondering if this is even possible how I'm doing it.

I hope someone can clear this up.

This is my PHP connection string:

```
$bdd= new PDO ("mysql:host=phpmyadmin.webserver.roc-teraa.nl;port=3306;dbname=wikiparks","$username", "$password");
```

This is my C# code:

```
 private void btnToevoegen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                NameValueCollection ParkInfo = new NameValueCollection();
                ParkInfo.Add("ParkNaam", txbPretpark.Text);
                ParkInfo.Add("ParkLocatie", txbLocatiePretpark.Text);
                ParkInfo.Add("ParkOpeningsDagen", txbOpeningsDagen.Text);
                ParkInfo.Add("ParkOpeningsTijden", txbOpeningsTijden.Text);
                ParkInfo.Add("ParkPrijzen", txbPrijzenPretpark.Text);
                ParkInfo.Add("ParkLeeftijden", txbLeeftijdPretpark.Text);
                ParkInfo.Add("ParkTags", txbTags.Text);
                ParkInfo.Add("ParkBeschrijving", rtbBeschrijving.Text);

                byte[] InsertPark = client.UploadValues("http://localhost:8080/WikiParks/index.php", "POST", ParkInfo);
                client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "binary/octet-stream");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Pretpak succesvol toegevoegd aan de Database");
            }


        }
    }
```

and I was wondering if I'm using the correct host and if this is a good connection string to use?

Comment: I didn't get it. You're working on a C# application and you're showing the PHP code. Also, you have to know if the host is correct, there is no way others can know it. We can check if your connection string is right, for example, but host may be anything.

Comment: You shouldn't change the host depending on the user. If you are all sharing the same database, the host will be the same for everyone. Assuming each member of your group has their own user account set up in the database, they would only need to change the username and password when they try to connect, regardless of whether they're using PHP, C#, anything.

Comment: I've added the C# code.
and I think this is my host http://phpmyadmin.webserver.roc-teraa.nl/

Or am I wrong?